# Getting a random number between 0 and 0.06 in Java?

Tags: java, random

How do you get random `Double` values between 0.0 and 0.06 in Java?

Comment: This is actually not as easy as it sounds. +1

Comment: When you say 'between', do you want the end points to be included or excluded as possible return values?

Comment: You should clarify whether what you want is numbers in [0,0.06] or [0,0.06). The former, where the interval is closed (i.e., the endpoints are included) is not the same as the latter, where you can never get 0.06 as a value.

Comment: @AakashM, @uckelman: that's not relevant in this case, because 0.06 can't be represented exactly as a `double`, so it can't ever be returned anyway. Or phrased differently: he can only ever achieve "[0.0, 0.6]".

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html suggests it can be, as it happens (it's 1.92 / 32 and 1.92 can be represented exactly in a 52-bit mantissa)

Comment: @AakashM: using `new BigDecimal(double).toString()` in Java will give you the exact decimal representation of any double value. This prints "0.59999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375", which is awefully close to 0.6, but still not there.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`nextDouble()` returns a random floating-point number uniformly distributed between 0 and 1. Simply scale the result as follows:

```
Random generator = new Random();
double number = generator.nextDouble() * .06;
```

See [this documentation](http://www.cs.geneseo.edu/~baldwin/reference/random.html) for more examples of Random.

Comment: Also you may have to check that number is less than < 0.06, floating point operations are not exact [in the sense there is always some error/uncertainty which accumulates over many floating point operations].

Comment: Also beware of using a new instance of `Random` for every number you need. In that sense, uckelman's answer below is better as it specifically avoids that common mistake.

Answer (score 7):

This will give you a random double in the interval [0,0.06):

```
double r = Math.random()*0.06;
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid the inexactness of floating point values you can use a double/integer calculation which is more accurate (at least on x86/x64 platforms)

```
double d = Math.random() * 6 / 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to have a look at the [Random](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this java doc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28%29) (though watch the boundary condition):

```
 new Random().nextDouble() * 0.06
```